# How to alert the user if there is already schedule is set of the day?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

Here I'm using jQuery to alert a user if he/she want to add a schedule on a particular time but that time is already exists in the db. Suppose let us take an example of this there is a `User` having a schedule on `Monday` is `8:00AM to 10:00AM` and there is another schedule of same user is `1:00PM to 3:00PM` but if the user want to add another time of PM like `1:00PM to 4:00PM` or `1:30PM to 4:00PM` then the system first check that there is time exists between them then it will alert. This all is done in golang api then there is a little problem in Jquery like I retrieved all data from my api but while arranging them like I told above that `1:00PM to 3:00PM` if user want to add the other schedule like `1:30PM to 4:00PM` then it will show the other times too like `8:00AM to 10:00AM` too why it is showing like that below code I'm using:-

```
for(var m = 0; m< timearray.length; m++){
        for (var l = 0; l < array_time.length; l++) {
           if (array_time[l].start_time == timearray[m].start_time && array_time[l].end_time == timearray[m].end_time) {
                console.log("hello 1")
                result_dates.push(convertTime24to12(secondsTimeSpanToHMS(timearray[m].start_time))+" "+convertTime24to12(secondsTimeSpanToHMS(timearray[m].end_time)));
                }
                if (array_time[l].start_time < timearray[m].start_time && array_time[l].end_time == timearray[m].end_time) {
                    console.log("hello 2")
                    result_dates.push(convertTime24to12(secondsTimeSpanToHMS(timearray[m].start_time))+" "+convertTime24to12(secondsTimeSpanToHMS(timearray[m].end_time)));
                }
                if (array_time[l].start_time == timearray[m].start_time && array_time[l].end_time > timearray[m].end_time) {
                    console.log("hello 3")
                    result_dates.push(convertTime24to12(secondsTimeSpanToHMS(timearray[m].start_time))+" "+convertTime24to12(secondsTimeSpanToHMS(timearray[m].end_time)));
                }
                if (array_time[l].start_time < timearray[m].start_time && array_time[l].end_time > timearray[m].end_time) {
                    console.log("hello 4")
                    result_dates.push(convertTime24to12(secondsTimeSpanToHMS(timearray[m].start_time))+" "+convertTime24to12(secondsTimeSpanToHMS(timearray[m].end_time)));
                }
                if (array_time[l].start_time > timearray[m].start_time && array_time[l].end_time == timearray[m].end_time){ 
                    console.log("hello 5")
                    result_dates.push(convertTime24to12(secondsTimeSpanToHMS(timearray[m].start_time))+" "+convertTime24to12(secondsTimeSpanToHMS(timearray[m].end_time)));
                }
                if (array_time[l].start_time > timearray[m].start_time || array_time[l].end_time > timearray[m].end_time){ 
                    for (var n = timearray[m].start_time; n < timearray[m].end_time; n++) {
                        if (timearray[m].start_time == array_time[l].start_time) {
                            console.log("hello 6")
                            result_dates.push(convertTime24to12(secondsTimeSpanToHMS(timearray[m].start_time))+" "+convertTime24to12(secondsTimeSpanToHMS(timearray[m].end_time)));
                        }
                    }
                }
       }
    }   
 }
```

Here `timearray` is a array in which there is scheduled time is set and in the  `array_time` the time user want to save in the database.

- In first condition it checks if start time and end time are same then this will execute.
- In second condition if the start time is less than the existing time and end time is equal to the existing end time then this will execute.
- In third condition if the end time is more than the existing end time and the start time is same then this will execute.
- In forth condition if start time is less than the existing start time and end time is more then the existing end time then this will execute.
- In fifth condition it will check that if start time is less than the existing start time and end time remains same then this will executed.
- **Not Working properly**:- In this condition if the user adds start time like `"1:30PM to 4:00PM"` then it will not work properly it will also push the data of the timing `"8:00AM to 10:00AM"`. What should I have to apply on it that it will show only the time between the `"1:00PM to 3:00PM"`.

Can anybody please help me to solving this problem. Thank you. Hope you will understand what I want to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sixth statement be like this:-

```
if (array_time[l].start_time >= timearray[m].start_time &&
   array_time[l].start_time <= timearray[m].end_time && 
   array_time[l].end_time > timearray[m].end_time) {
//do stuff 
}
```